# Prevent datetime.strptime from exit in case of format mismatch

Tags: python, datetime

I am parsing dates from a measurement file (about 200k lines). The format is a date and a measurement. The date format is "2013-08-07-20-46" or in time  format "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M". Ever so often the time stamp has a bad character. (The data came from a serial link which had interruptions). The entry would look like : 201-08-11-05-15 .

My parsing line to convert the time string into seconds is :

```
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").timetuple())
```

I got it online and don't fully understand how it work. (But it works)

My problem is to prevent the program from throwing error exit when a format mismatch happens. Is there a way to prevent the strptime to no exit but gracefully return an error flag in which case I would simple discard the data line and move on to the next. Yes, I can perform a pattern check with regexp but I was wondering if some smart mismatch handling is already built into strptime.

Append @ Anand S Kumar

It worked for a few bad lines but then it failed.

```
fp = open('bmp085.dat', 'r')
for line in fp:
    [dt,t,p]= string.split(line)
    try:
        sec= time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").timetuple()) - sec0
    except ValueError:
        print 'Bad data : ' + line
        continue #If you are doing this in a loop (looping over the lines) so that it moves onto next iteration
    print sec, p ,t
t_list.append(sec)
p_list.append(p)

fp.close()
```

Output:

```
288240.0 1014.48 24.2
288540.0 1014.57 24.2
288840.0 1014.46 24.2
Bad data : �013-08-11-05-05   24.2!  1014.49

Bad data : 2013=0▒-11-05-10  �24.2   1014.57

Bad data : 201�-08-11-05-15   24.1   1014.57

Bad data : "0�#-08-1!-p5-22   24.1   1014.6

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>>
```

Append @ Anand S Kumar

It crashed again.

```
for line in fp:
    print line
    dt,t,p = line.split(' ',2)
    try:
        sec= time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").timetuple()) - sec0
    except ValueError:
        print 'Bad data : ' + line
        continue #If you are doing this in a loop (looping over the lines) so that it moves onto next iteration
    print sec, p ,t
```

Failed  :

```
2013-08-11�06-t5   03/9   9014.y

Bad data : 2013-08-11�06-t5   03/9   9014.y

2013-08-11-06-50  (23.   1014.96

295440.0 (23.   1014.96

2013-08-11-06%55  23.9 !�1015.01

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str
>>> fp.close()
>>>
```

Comment: `try - except` is what you  looking for.

Comment: @GertGottschalk you can check my updated answer for the second error.

Comment: @Anand S Kumar Thank you. At the point of checking the input line it might be simplest to use regexp (just check for presence of 3 strings). I haven't decided yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`try..except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) catching any `ValueError` and if any such value error occurs, move onto the next line. Example -

```
try:
    time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").timetuple())
except ValueError:
    continue #If you are doing this in a loop (looping over the lines) so that it moves onto next iteration
```

If you are doing something else (maybe like a function call for each line , then return None or so in the `except` block)

---

The second `ValueError` you are getting should be occuring in line -

```
[dt,t,p]= string.split(line)
```

This issue is occur because there maybe a particular line that is resulting in more than 3 elements. One thing you can do for this would be to use the `maxspplit` argument from `str.split()` to split maximum 3 times. Example -

```
dt,t,p = line.split(None,2)
```

Or if you really want to use `string.split()` -

```
[dt,t,p]= string.split(line,None,2)
```

Or if you are not expecting `space` inside any of the fields, you can include the line causing the `ValueError` inside the `try..except` block and treat it as a bad line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `try - except` in a `for`-loop:

```
for dt in data:
    try:
        print time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").timetuple())
    except ValueError:
        print "Wrong format!"
        continue
```

Output for `data = ["1998-05-14-15-45","11998-05-14-15-45","2002-05-14-15-45"]`:

```
895153500.0
Wrong format!
1021383900.0
```