# Using re.findall to extract data from a line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying (and failing so far) to extract time and two measurement data from a text line (read from a file)

The lines have following format

```
"2013-08-07-21-25   26.0   1015.81"
```

I tried (among other):

```
>>> re.findall(r"([0-9,-]+)|(\d+.\d+)", "2013-08-07-21-25   26.0   1015.81")
[('2013-08-07-21-25', ''), ('26', ''), ('0', ''), ('1015', ''), ('81', '')]
```

And only got entertaining (but not desired) results.

I would like to find a solution like this:

```
date, temp, press = re.findall(r"The_right_stuff", "2013-08-07-21-25   26.0   1015.81")
print date + '\n' + temp + '\n' + press + '\n'
2013-08-07-21-25
26.0
1015.81
```

Even better if the assignment could be stuck into a test to check if the number of matches is correct.

```
if len(date, temp, press = re.findall(r"The_rigth_stuff", "2013-08-07-21-25   26.0   1015.81")) == 3:
    print 'Got good data.'
    print date + '\n' + temp + '\n' + press + '\n'
```

The lines have be transmitted via serial connection and might have bad (i.e. unexpected) characters interspersed. So it does not work to separate by string index.

See [Prevent datetime.strptime from exit in case of format mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008354/prevent-datetime-strptime-from-exit-in-case-of-format-mismatch).

---

Edit @hjpotter92

I mentioned there were corrupted lines from the serial transmission. The below example failed the split solution.

```
2013-08-1q-07-15   23.8   1014.92
2013-08-11-07-20   23.8   101$96
6113-p8-11-0-25   23.8   1015*04
```

Assigning the list of measurements into a numpy array failed.

```
>>> p_arr= np.asfarray(p_list, dtype='float')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 105, in asfarray
    return asarray(a, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 460, in asarray
        return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 101$96
```

I put the set of data [here](http://drgert.dyndns.ws:8000/download/bmp085.dat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `re.split` since the data is separated by horizontal-space characters:

```
date, temp, press = re.split('\s+', "2013-08-07-21-25   26.0   1015.81")
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>> date, temp, press = re.split('\s+', "2013-08-07-21-25   26.0   1015.81")
>>> print date
2013-08-07-21-25
>>> print temp
26.0
>>> print press
1015.81
```

Comment: What about use built-in function `.split()` like `date, temp, press = "2013-08-07-21-25   26.0   1015.81".split()`?

Comment: There's no reason to use the overhead from re for a task like this when a standard delimiter (whitespace) is present.

Answer (score 1):

```
print [i+j for i,j in re.findall(r"\b(\d+(?!\.)(?:[,-]\d+)*)\b|\b(\d+\.\d+)\b", "2013-08-07-21-25   26.0   1015.81")]
```

You have to prevent first group from taking anything away from what is meant from the second group.

Output:`['2013-08-07-21-25', '26.0', '1015.81']`